# Incorrect syntax near UPDATE, expecting external error when creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('*[dbo].[UpdateData]*', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN    

CREATE PROC [dbo].[UpdateData]   
AS    
UPDATE [DB1].[dbo].[Staff]
SET
[Name1]= 'Value1',
[Name2]= 'N2',
[Name3]= 'N3'
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Staff] s
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[Table1] si on s.[ID]=si.[ID]

 RETURN;       
END
```

Does any one know why the above code snippet is generating the "Incorrect syntax near UPDATE, expecting external" at the UPDATE key word in the line below `UPDATE [DB1].[dbo].[Staff]`

Comment: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "The CREATE PROCEDURE statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch."

Comment: You're also missing a comma after `[Name2]='N2'`

Answer (score -1):

Change the update query like this

```
UPDATE [DB1].[dbo].[Staff]
SET
[Name1]= s.[BPNumber],
[Name2]= 'N2',
[Name3]= 'N3'
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Staff] s
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[Table1] si on s.[ID]=si.[ID]
```